# Strange Theme Error - parent style occasionally showing though child theme

Tags: themes, css, child-theme, parent-theme

I am creating a website using WordPress 4.6.1, it is using a slightly modified version of the '2013 Blue Sequence' child theme, from the parent 'Twenty Thirteen'.
This child theme recolours the oranges/browns of the parent to various blues.

This works excellently across the board, except from a small quick which I can't nail down the cause of.

The menu dropdowns are in a bark blue colour, which changes to a lighter shade as each item is hovered over, see (a).

However, if you click the link, then move your mouse away, instead of staying blue while the page changes, the orange colour of the parent theme 'shows through', as in (b).

[image: The two views of the dropdown menu]

When inspecting the CSS of the element, it can be seen that the child theme overwrites the colours of the parent:

[image: Inspecting the CSS of the element]

So, it is almost like the child theme is getting disregarded during the page change?

While, I know, this is only a small issue, it has annoyed me and I can't suss it out! Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks! :)

Comment: Can you provide live example of the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent theme has a active selector which the child may not have.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Comment: Aha! Thanks very much :)

Not :active, but the child wasn't changing the :focus style. So, I just added that in and that sorted it out.